# Bigcommerce API - Producst custom fields

Tags: bigcommerce

I need a help regarding Bigcommerce API

How to fetch product ID using custom fields in Bigcommerce API.

ex: I have a custom field Name "option1" and value "checked" for a product  I need to get the product Id based on the option name "option1".

Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which language you're working with, but I'm most familiar with C#.  My solution may be prohibitive if you have hundreds of items in your store, as the first step is to GET an XML collection of products (if you prefer to use JSON, you can use JSON.NET to deserialize to XML).

This takes some looping, so define a variable to set the product id.

```
string prodID = String.Empty; //I used string to keep from converting, int would work
```

Then query the API for all products in your store.

```
string response = QueryAPI("https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/products", "GET");
```

This will return an XML string of all products in the store.  Create an XmlDocument to populate with these products:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(response);
```

Now you have a nicely structured list you can search using XPath expressions.

```
prodID = doc.SelectSingleNode("products/product[custom_fields/name == 'option1']/id").InnerText;
```

If "option1" is uniquely named among your products' custom fields, this should set prodID to the String value of the Product ID.